# Native to React Native call

Tags: ios, react-native

I need to send data time to time from Native to React Native. What is the best way to do that. I know we have `Native Modules` which allows us to make calls from React native to Native side but I want to do the opposite thing.

Can someone share some examples? ( I do not want to use the initial Props as I have to send the data time to time, based on the message received on the native side)

Answer (score 0):

You can send events to javascript side and listen for those events. You can read more about it on [Sending Events to Javascript](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios#sending-events-to-javascript) documentation.

> ### Sending Events to JavaScript
>
> The native module can signal events to JavaScript without being
>   invoked directly. The preferred way to do this is to subclass
>   `RCTEventEmitter`, implement `supportedEvents` and call self
>   `sendEventWithName`